# How can I store the link to an Image in a variable?

Tags: excel, vba

The first code is working, it will open the Image on my sheet.

```
ActiveCell.Select
Dim picname As String
picname = ActiveCell.Value

ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert "C:\Users\gaetan.affolter\Desktop\test.jpg "
```

But I need to have a variable as link, because the link changes all the time.

I have tried this code but I got an error.

> "Impossible to read the image picture propriety insert of the class
>   picture"

```
Worksheets("Feuil1").Range("A1").Value = Image3

Dim img As Picture

ActiveCell.Select
Dim picname As String
picname = ActiveCell.Value

Set img = ActiveSheet.Pictures.Insert(Image3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems to be a little muddled.

1. If the full path to the image is in cell `A1`, then your first line should be changed to:

   `Image3 = Worksheets("Feuil1").Range("A1").Value`
2. What are you doing with `picname`?  You declare and assign it but you are not using it here.